# Root Privileges Moving From MySQL to Mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb, migration, docker

I am experimenting with migrating my database from an older version of MySQL to a Mariadb Docker container. I am simply dumping the entire database and restoring it within Mariadb.

The only issue I've run into thus far is that there are a number of privileges that exist in Mariadb that do not exist in MySQL. As a result, my migrated root user is missing some privileges and is therefore unable to do the following:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
```

How can I grant my migrated root user the privileges which are unique to Mariadb when restoring from my dump wipes out the initial mariadb root user?